# Отправка сообщения в телеграм сразу нескольким пользователям

Tags: php, telegram

Есть телеграм бот. Я могу отправить менеджеру с его помощью уведомление о поступившем заказе с сайта. Вот такой php-скрипт используется у меня на сайте при оформлении заказа.

```
                $tg_user = 'XXXXXX'; 
                $bot_token = 'XXX:YYY';
                $params = array(
                    'chat_id' => $tg_user, 
                    'text' => $letter,
                    'parse_mode' => 'HTML',
                );                   
                $curl = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $bot_token . '/sendMessage'); 
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10); 
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
                $result = curl_exec($curl);
                curl_close($curl);                   
                var_dump(json_decode($result));
```

Проблема: менеджера целых три. И нужно отправлять это уведомление всем троим. Соответственно, `$tg_user` не один, а три. Вопрос: как лучше сделать? Трижды запускать скрипт с разными `$tg_user`? Или как-то можно по-другому? В API телеги искал, не нашел решения для массовой отправки.
Спасибо!

Comment: Создайте канал и пригласите туда всех менеджеров, чтобы робот туда им писал, а они видели и могли договориться о том кто займётся заказом?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov такая идея тоже пришла мне в голову, но если я меняю ID юзера на ID канала (они отличаются количеством цифр, и знаком минус перед ними), то бот не срабатывает. Не знаю, в чем причина.